# RelativeLayout refresh after view.setVisibility(View.GONE) and view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Tags: java, android, layout, visibility, android-relativelayout

Please look at the following image to understand the problem:

[image]

As you can see, there is a `RelativeLayout` which holds a custom `View` and a `LinearLayout`.
Between them, there is also another `View`, which `Visibility` is set to `GONE`.
Now, when I press the `Button`, I would like to change the visibility of that `GONE` View to `VISIBLE`, and rearrange the `RelativeLayout`, so that the third `View` gets between custom `View` and `LinearLayout`. When I press another button, I would like to make third view GONE again. How can I achieve that?

Here is my XML:

```
<view
    android:id="@+id/CanvasView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/HorizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    class="com.example.CanvasView"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    //SOME BUTTONS HERE
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_button_selector" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:text="Recognize"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I only setVisibility of the third view in OnClick() method, it will appear above LinearLayout and it will overlay the custom View (I tried it before). In other words, it will not move RelativeLayout up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
         findViewById(R.id.hiddenview).setVisibility(View.GONE);
         findViewById(R.id.relativelayout).invalidate();
     }
});
findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
         findViewById(R.id.hiddenview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         findViewById(R.id.relativelayout).invalidate();
     }
});
```

Comment: There is no repaint() method for RelativeLayout

Comment: invalidate also doesn't take effect. It seems like custom View is glued to LinearLayout... Any other ideas?

Comment: Does the view do what you would expect when you change the visibility in the interface designer? If not, check to make sure that your custom view depends on the location of the hidable view

Comment: You are right. I just found the problem. I was hardcoding:
         
         layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.linearLayout2);
         canvasView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); I had to change it to 
         layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.CandidatesHorizontalScrollView);

Answer (score -1):

In your activity, `onClick()` get the instance of that `GONE` view to `View.VISIBLE` so that it reappears between the two view.

```
 viewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

For this that in between `VIEW` should already be present in the xml, just that it is `GONE` by default!

Comment: This will make the third view appear above LinearLayout and it will overlay the custom View (I tried it before). In other words, it will not move RelativeLayout up.

Comment: @Marek i did not understand your point. Which `RelativeLayout` are you speaking about... the parent layout???

Comment: I mean that your solution will not work. What I want is to put third View between custom View and LinearLayout, so RelativeLayout would move up, and below it third Layout would appear.

Comment: can you use a linerlayout in place of your relative layout and then wrapcontent height for your third view should achieve this